# How to write HQL-query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

There is a table `CART_ITEMS`, where `drink_id` is the `id` of the drink, and `order_id` is the `id` of the order in which it is located, `count` is the amount of this drink in the order. You need to display the 6 most popular drinks from this table. I wrote the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT drink_id, sum(count) as count
FROM cart_items
GROUP BY drink_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 6
```

But how can we rewrite it in `HQL` now? I tried to write code, but the Intelij Idea swears at the `sum` and `limit` functions.

```java
@Query("select C.drink, sum(count) as count from CartItem C group by C.drink order by 2 DESC limit 6")
    List<Drink> getMostPopularDrinks();
```

CartItem:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "cart_items")
public class CartItem {

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class CartId implements Serializable {

        private Long order_id;

        private Long drink_id;
    }


    /**
     * key @EmbeddedId
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    private CartId cartId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "drink_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Drink drink;

    /**
     * Count of drink
     */
    private int count;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Sorry. I am translate

Comment: I don't think limit is supported as part of HQL.You can use nativeQuery. You can provide limitations by limitstatement in your SQL. And have nativeQuery = true in @Query annotation to consider this as a native SQL query.

`@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT drink_id, sum(count) as count FROM cart_items GROUP BY drink_id ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 6")
List<Drink> getMostPopularDrinks();`

Comment: please try to use PageRequest.of(0,5) this link may help you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting